# How to implement a calendar like google's with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, calendar

It should provide ease to add event to the calendar.

When I click on the cell,should let me edit the notes.

**EDIT**

I've looked through many calendars but none of them meet the requirement that it should let the user add notes easily!

Answer (score 4):

[jMonthCalendar](http://www.bytecyclist.com/projects/jmonthcalendar/) and [jQuery Week Calendar](http://www.redredred.com.au/projects/jquery-week-calendar/) are both pretty good. If you want to roll your sleeves up and get your hands dirty making your own, there's [a nice tutorial](http://www.stefanoverna.com/log/create-astonishing-ical-like-calendars-with-jquery) online demonstrating how to make an iCal-like jQuery Calendar. There's an online demo too: [http://www.stefanoverna.com...ical_like_calendar/](http://www.stefanoverna.com/wp-content/tutorials/ical_like_calendar/)

Comment: None of them support adding notes.

Comment: Pick one an extend it. Most of the work has already been done.

Answer (score 3):

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Also if you are interested in iCal like calendar: http://www.stefanoverna.com/log/create-astonishing-ical-like-calendars-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Gotta bump for my favorite... [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/).  Does Day/Week/Month view, with a really great API, and optional support for jQuery UI Themes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one I put together. I sorta looks like Google Calendar.

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-frontier-calendar/

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you really need. Since you didn't 100% specify it, I point you to the possibility of embedding a publicly shared Google Calendar on your site:
http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=41207

Since you're so strict on having the exact same functionality as on GCalendar it may satisfy your needs.